# Secure private connection between 2 linux/ubuntu systems? openvpn?

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I'm looking to use something like OpenVPN between 2 systems to create a secure private and reliable connection.
However on the OpenVPN site they don't have much information regarding Linux VPN clients (only servers).
Is there a way to have one Ubuntu OpenVPN server with the other Ubuntu client connecting directly to it?  This would be all using the SERVER versions of the OS without any X or GUI stuff.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Designate one machine as a OpenVPN server and one machine as a client. The client connects to the server and you will have a bi-directional VPN link. If both of the machines are always connected with a static IP, it does not really matter which one is the server and which one is the client.

I do not understand how X or GUI stuff or server/non-server versions of operating systems matter. OpenVPN does not care.

<strike>Another possibility is **tinc**. It is easy and simple like OpenVPN.</strike>

Comment: don't use tinc. Read this http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/linux_vpn.txt

Comment: @Geoff, that is interesting. I edited my answer to redact the recommendation to use it.

Comment: @goo, that article is from Sep 2003, could tinc have been ameliorated since?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, works fine. You'll want to make sure that you don't have a password on your keys, though; otherwise you'll need to enter a password on each boot. And that means it should have its permissions properly restricted (not that they were open in the first place... right? ;) ).

You should write a client configuration and place the file in the OpenVPN configuration directory with a filename ending in `.conf`. On startup, every `.conf` file in the directory will spawn an OpenVPN process. A client conf will connect to an OpenVPN server, a server conf will spawn an OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a huge fan of [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle#readme):

> The most basic use of sshuttle looks like: ./sshuttle -r username@sshserver 0.0.0.0/0 -vv
>
> If you would also like your DNS queries to be proxied through the DNS server of the server you are connect to: ./sshuttle --dns -vvr username@sshserver 0/0

See [a previous answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/285781/quick-and-dirty-vpn-linux-to-linux/285858#285858) for more details.